# ASP.NET Authorization what does the * and ? mean?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

In ASP.NET I often see (and have copied the following) but never really understood the difference between the * and ? symbols.

for example

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*" />
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Just wondering if anyone can tell me the difference?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` means anonymous users.

`*` means all users.

Answer (score 1):

The * is a wildcard meaning "everyone", ? means anonymous users.

Comment: Can you let me,what is the actual difference between anonymous user and  everyone?

Comment: Everyone includes anonymous users - but also logged in users.